# Как правильно отправить клавиатуру ВК?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Задача: отправить inline-клавиатуру по вызову команды. Клавиатура должна содержать одну кнопку с ссылкой.

Реализация:

```
if event.text == '!command':
   keyboard_new_send = VkKeyboard(**settings)
   keyboard_new_send.add_openlink_button(label='Open url', link=f"{download_url}, payload=None")
   
   vk.messages.send(
               user_id=event.user_id,
               random_id=get_random_id(),
               message=f'Custom message',
               keyboard=keyboard_new_send
   )
```

Выходные данные:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\python-bots\vk_exc_bot\bot.py", line 371, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\python-bots\vk_exc_bot\bot.py", line 362, in main
    vk.messages.send(
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 696, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\ИНФА\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 656, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: keyboard contains incorrect JSON
```

Вопрос: каким образом можно избавиться от этой ошибки и отправить клавиатуру? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: так в ошибке ж написано, что какой то из параметров клавиатуры не валиден или отсутствует. ошибки для того и пишутся, чтоб их читать

Comment: @finally это я понял, пытался изменять кнопку в соответствии с документацией, ничего не помогало

Comment: Попробуйте `keyboard=keyboard_new_send.get_keyboard()`.

Answer (score 1):

исходя из [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor), метод `add_openlink_button` должен выглядеть так:

```py
add_openlink_button(label, link, payload=None):
    Добавить кнопку с ссылкой
    Максимальное количество кнопок на строке - MAX_BUTTONS_ON_LINE
    Parameters: 
    label (str) – Надпись на кнопке
    link (str) – ссылка, которую необходимо открыть по нажатию на кнопку
    payload (str or list or dict) – Параметр для callback api
```

откуда можно понять, что кварг `payload=None` вы "упустили"

Comment: Та же самая ошибка